# Android cannot open connection with SignlaR - IIS

Tags: android, iis, signalr

I have created `asp.net core` - `signalr app`.

It is hosted on IIS, and this is the url:

`https://192.168.1.167/javasignalr/`

The Signaling hub is on this address:

`https://192.168.1.167/javasignalr/signaling`

I tested the app, the `signalr` works as expected, i.e. the connection is started, and I got results from my signaling hub to the UI.

After that, I created new android project, and I followed the official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/java-client?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

So in my Andoid project, in `MainActivity` I have this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        HubConnection hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create("https://192.168.1.167/javasignalr/signaling").build();

        hubConnection.on("newMessage", (message) -> {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("This is Title");
            builder.setMessage("This is message for Alert Dialog");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Positive Button", (dialog, which) -> onBackPressed());
            builder.setNegativeButton("Negative Button", (dialog, which) -> dialog.cancel());
            builder.show();
        }, String.class);

        hubConnection.start();

    }
```

But when debugging, I can see that the `hubConnection` status is:

**`disconnected`**

Any idea why this is happening, and how can I establish connection:

android client < - > iis dotnet core app

Comment: Do you miss something from this class as setup *(token or handshake etc)*? : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.signalr._http_hub_connection_builder?view=aspnet-signalr-java